# How to disable warnings about 'this' and strict mode using JSHint?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jshint

I am writing a web app using AngularJS (v1.5) so I have some controllers, and in those controllers I am often declaring something like :

```
function myController($someDirectives, ...){
    var ctrl = this;
    // My code
}
```

The thing is when I JSHint my code, I get this warning message for all of my 'this' declared in controllers :

> If a strict mode function is executed using function invocation, its 'this' value will be undefined.

I must precise that in my .jshintrc file, I set `"strict":false`.
Does anyone know how to disable this message in particular?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not in a position to test, but I think, if you change the function name to MyController, it is then recognized as a constructor function and that error won't be given. Give that a shot.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. In may case, the recursive function in question is being passed 'this' via functionName.call.

Comment: Indeed, Ken's suggestion seems to work. For me, it is just more simple to add a `"validthis":true` in my .jshintrc .

Comment: Does anyone know why the controller name has to start with a capital to fix this? so odd.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

set the configuration in `.jshintrc` file

```
{
  "validthis": true // Tolerate using this in a non-constructor 
}
```

Comment: This was what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

You can always override [jshint options](http://jshint.com/docs/options/) in the code-block ie.

```
/* jshint validthis: true */
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, with a very similar environment `angular 1.5.5` always getting the same lint warning:

If a strict mode function is executed using function invocation, its 'this' value will be undefined.

I've changed the name of my component's main function starting with upper-case and the warning disappeared

`function MyController($someDirectives, ...){`

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue. I'm doing "[indirect invocation](https://rainsoft.io/gentle-explanation-of-this-in-javascript/)" with the function in question, not "function invocation", and 'this' is referenced many times in the function body.

In my case, I was having so many of these "errors" that jsHint quit before scanning my whole script.

To get around this I put this at the top of my script-file:

```
/*jshint maxerr: 10000 */
```

It did not suppress the errors, but at least it allowed me to scroll down to see jsHint's analysis of the entire script.